# Sorting a text file by date - Date looks like DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, sorting, bufferedreader

I am trying to sort the dates from the earliest to the latest.
I was thinking about using the bufferedreader and do a try searching the first 2 characters of the string and then the 4th and 5th characters and finally the 7th and 8th characters, ignoring the slashes.

The following is an example of the text file I have:

04/24/2010 -  2000.0 (Deposit)

09/05/2010 -  20.0 (Fees)

02/30/2007 -  600.0 (Deposit)

06/15/2009 -  200.0 (Fees)

08/23/2010 -  300.0 (Deposit)

06/05/2006 -  500.0 (Fees)

Comment: Welcome to SO, John!  Aside from the fact that you're only checking two of the year digits, your algorithm seems like it would succeed.  Do you have a question about it?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I am just getting started into programming and I am trying to wrap my head around a lot of the this.

Answer (score 2):

[How do I sort records in a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740936/how-do-i-sort-records-in-a-text-file-using-java)

This clubbed with changing your dates to the desired format using `SimpleDateFormat` in `getField(String line)` should get you going.

Comment: I noticed that it did not allow for duplicate strings when I tried to run it, as per a note in that link you gave me said as well. Also, when I run the sort it puts it into a single line. As far as the SimpleDateFormat, I would use the MM/DD/YYYY I am assuming. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, a map would not allow duplicate keys. So, you might want to change the value in map to a `List<String>` so that the code looks like (Code given just for idea-sake; Did not compile/test)
`
List<String> records;
  while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
  if(map.get(getField(line) != null) {
    records = map.get(getField(line));
  } else {
    records = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
  records.add(line);
  map.put(getField(line),records);
}

`
Similarly the loop that writes records out will deal with `List` values in the map.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file? I would just read in every line, create a date object for each of the lines, and then call `Collections.sort(list<myobjectwithdate>)`

Date provides a comparator, so you could very easily store everything in memory, sort it, and then write it back to file.

```
class LineAndDate implements Comparable{
  private Date date;
  private String line;

  public int compareTo( Object other )
  {
    return date.compareTo( ((LineAndDate)other).date;
  }

}
```

Store a `List<LineAndDate>` in memory, and then you should just be able to call `Collections.sort(myList)` and write that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dates to the desired format using [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and sort on that.