# Java scanner + sort

Tags: java, sorting

Okay, first post, yay!
Now I know this topic has been beaten to death already. But here's the question :

> Write a program that reads words separated by spaces from a text file
>   and displays words in ascending order. (If two words are the same,
>   display only one). Pass the text filename from the command line.
>   Assume that the text file contains only words separated by spaces.

Now I have the reading from the file part figured out. But how do I "pass the filename from the command line"? And then there's the uniqueness factor.

Help?

Edit:
Thanks guys for your help. Here's where I stand now:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Splittext {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];
        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)));
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(s.next());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
               if (s != null) {
                   s.close();
                }
            }


       TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();

       ts.add(s);

       Iterator it = ts.iterator();

       while(it.hasNext()) {
           String value = (String)it.next();
           System.out.println("Result :" + result);
        }
    }        
}
```

But this yields : No suitable method for add (java.util.Scanner); method java.util.TreeSet.add(java.lang.String) is not applicable.

Sorry for the noob questions! Really appreaciate the help :)

Comment: `String filename = args[0];`

Comment: @RobHeiser The homework tag is deprecated. Please don't use it.

Comment: [Command line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). [Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740936/how-do-i-sort-records-in-a-text-file-using-java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fileName = args[0];
    Scanner s = null;

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Run this like

```
java classname readthisfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I "pass the filename from the command line"?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    final String filename = args[0];
    // ...
}
```

> And then there's the uniqueness factor.

And sorting factor.

1. Insert all the words into [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).
2. Iterate through it and print values. They will be sorted and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function has `String[] args` passed into to it when you kick off your application, this is where you access you input arguments.

e.g.:

```
java -cp . my.class.Example Happy Days
```

Would see the Example class receiving this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // args.length == 2
  // args[0] = "Happy"
  // args[1] = "Days"
}
```