# How do i sort data in text file with Java? vol#2

Tags: java, sorting, text, split

I'm trying to sort data I have in a text file. Each row of the file contains the fields:

```
name,surname,age,weight,height
```

I tried to split each line up by using [Peter Dolberg's Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740936/how-do-i-sort-records-in-a-text-file-using-java/740977#740977) - but it doesn't work for duplicate keys. What can I do instead?

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You can use [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be create a class say **PersonalInfo** with instance variable name,surname,age,weight,height. Also write their getter and setter methods.

Then create an array of PersonalInfo objects(by reading from your file ).

```
PersonalInfo employeeInfo[] = new PersonalInfo[3];
```

Then define a Comparator on the basis you would like to compare. For example for age -

```
 class AgeComparator implements Comparator{

public int compare(Object ob1, Object ob2){
    int ob1Age = ((PersonalInfo)ob1).getAge();        
    int ob2Age = ((PersonalInfo)ob2).getAge();

    if(ob1Age > ob2Age)
        return 1;
    else if(ob1Age < ob2Age)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;    
  }
}
```

Then you can simply use this comparator to sort your data.

```
Arrays.sort(employeeInfo, new AgeComparator());
```

If you wish to sort the data taking all factors into consideration then you can add that logic to your Comparator class.